# Add external C library on Embbeded coder Simulink (for Xilinx "Zedboard" target Xilinx SDK) in S-Builder

Tags: simulink, xilinx, s-function, zynq

I'm currently working on a project to be implemented on a Xilinx Zedboard, using Simulink Embedded Coder methodology.

Now I have to build a block that connects to a database (via MySQL, using the C library). The problem is that I don't know how to specify the path for cross-compiling this simulink block after `#include <mysql.h>`, in the S-function Builder.

Comment: I did a similar block for sqlite3 but I wrote the entire S-function (I did not use the builder). You need to link the lib file too. Check the Library Pane from the dialog box in S-function Builder: http://se.mathworks.com/help/simulink/sfg/s-function-builder-dialog-box.html#f8-107343

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a similar block for `sqlite3` but I wrote the entire `S-function` (I did not use the `S-function builder`). However, you need to link the `lib` file too (there has to be a `mysql.lib` file or some file with a similar name). You specify this link in the `Library Pane` from the `S-function Builder` dialog box. More info at this [link](http://se.mathworks.com/help/simulink/sfg/s-function-builder-dialog-box.html#f8-107343).